# Styling the \part page

Tags: sectioning, parts

I'm using `\part` for defining parts of my "book". The thing is, that the part takes a whole page. I use `\documentclass[12pt]{book}`.

I want to style the `\part` in a way that it looks like the `fncychap` style `Conny` and don't take a whole page.

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: I'm sorry for not understanding, but what do you mean by "a whole site"?

Comment: I think he means "a whole page".

Comment: Correct. The current style of `\part` takes an entire page.

Comment: Maybe not what you are looking for, but the [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) class provides options for styling the layout of the `\part`-page, as described in section 6.4 of the manual.

Comment: I already had a look on that. The thing is that I want to avoid reformatting my entire document.

Comment: In order to make `\part` not take a whole page, you need to make `\chapter` not start on a new page too, assuming you have a `\chapter` after every `\part`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a version using the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package.  I've made the `\part` and `chapter` styles identical, and roughly imitated the `Conny` style. You probably don't want to do exactly this, but it should be enough to get you started.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleclass{\part}{top} % make part like a chapter
\titleformat{\part}
[display]
{\centering\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
{\titlerule[5pt]\vspace{3pt}\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{3pt}\MakeUppercase{\partname} \thepart}
{0pt}
{\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{1pc}\huge\MakeUppercase}
%
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
%
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight} % make chapter like a section (no newpage)
\titleformat{\chapter}
[display]
{\centering\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
{\titlerule[5pt]\vspace{3pt}\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{3pt}\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
{0pt}
{\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{6pt}\huge\MakeUppercase}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}



\begin{document}
\part{A part}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for my late answer, but today I figured out that `\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}` seems to break the links to my toc (list of tables, etc). I'm using `\tableofcontents \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}`. See the image for an example: ![Screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/339/screenshot20111109at121h.png/). (left: all link to page I).

Comment: Is there a way to remove the part title all together? I want to use parts to organize the table of contents, but I don't need the part titles in the text. Thanks

Comment: @steffen If you don't need any reference to parts in the main text, then you can just add the lines directly to the TOC. E.g. `\newcommand{\tocpart}[1]{\stepcounter{part}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\thepart\quad#1}}` and then use `\tocpart{Title of Part}` in the text. But if you want part names to appear in the headers, for example, you'll need to do something more fancy, in which case I would ask a new question asking how to do that.