# \minitoc on the \part-page

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, parts, minitoc

I would like to modify the `\part`page such that it shows a table of contents of that part. Preferably also one or two levels deeper than the toc in the beginning of the document.

In [styling the \part page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30432/styling-the-part-page) Alan Munn shows how to edit the page,

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec,minitoc}  
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}
{\centering\normalfont\Huge\bfseries} 
{} 
{0pt} 
{}

\begin{document}
\tabkeofcontents

\part{This is the Part}
\minitoc %\parttoc,\doparttoc

\chapter{This is its first chapter}
\chapter{This is its second chapter}
\end{document}
```

but how do I add the 'minitoc'? In the above snippet neither `\minitoc` nor `\parttoc`or `\doparttoc` have any effect. `\minitoc` only works for chapters - not parts. Is there any other option or a smart modification I did not find?

Comment: ... edited the code snippet

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you are using `titlesec` it's not convenient to use `minitoc`. The following remark appears in the `minitoc` documentation:

> The `titlesec` package redefines the sectionning commands in a way
>   completely alien to the standard LaTeX way; hence `minitoc` and
>   `titlesec-titletoc` are fundamentaly incompatible, and it is very sad.

However, you can easily produce the ToCs using [titletoc](https://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}  

\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}
  {\centering\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{This is the Part}
\startcontents[parts]
\printcontents[parts]{}{-1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}}

\chapter{First part. This is its first chapter}
\section{First part. Section}
\subsection{First part. Subsection}
\subsubsection{First part. Subsubsection}
\paragraph{First part. Paragraph}
\subparagraph{First part. Subparagraph}
\chapter{First part. This is its second chapter}

\stopcontents[parts]

\part{This is the Part}
\startcontents[parts]
\printcontents[parts]{}{-1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}}

\chapter{Second part. This is its first chapter}
\section{Second part. Section}
\subsection{Second part. Subsection}
\subsubsection{Second part. Subsubsection}
\paragraph{Second part. Paragraph}
\subparagraph{Second part. Subparagraph}

\end{document}
```

Comment: adding `\usepackage{hyperref}` to the solution yields an error _perhaps a missing \item_ in the created '.ptc' file. I am not able to solve this, is it best to post a new question?

Comment: @D.Roepo I just did a test adding `hyperref` to my answer and everything worked OK (no errors) on my system (TeX Live2013). If you are getting some error(s), it would be best to open a new follow-up question including there a MWE allowing us to reproduce the problem (and perhaps providing a link to this question).

Comment: Is it possible to alter the tocdepth of the 'minitoc' displayed on the part page _within_ a part? I do not want multi-page tocs in the middle of the document. Simply changing it by `\printcontents[parts]{}{-1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}` did not do it...