# Customizing part and chapter section

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec, parts

I want to change appearance of `part` and `chapter` titles in my report. I already found few examples here, but now I'm trying to combine them to get what I need. Let's start from what we have in [Styling the \part page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30432/styling-the-part-page). I don't want full page just for part title, just to show it on top of the new page and after this to show chapter title. However, I would like to have part title as it is in example 14 on [this page](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html), that is to have "chapter 1" between lines. And yes, I would like to have a word "Chapter" although it comes from `part` command.

I tried to copy some parts from one example into another, but doesn't work. Will appreciate your help.

Effect I want to achieve, obtained by `part` command:

[image]

This is working example from accepted answer in mentioned question.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleclass{\part}{top} % make part like a chapter
\titleformat{\part}
[display]
{\centering\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
{\titlerule[5pt]\vspace{3pt}\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{3pt}\MakeUppercase{\partname} \thepart}
{0pt}
{\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{1pc}\huge\MakeUppercase}
%
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
%
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight} % make chapter like a section (no newpage)
\titleformat{\chapter}
[display]
{\centering\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
{\titlerule[5pt]\vspace{3pt}\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{3pt}\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
{0pt}
{\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{6pt}\huge\MakeUppercase}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}



\begin{document}
\part{A part}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `article` does not provide `chapter`s.

Comment: @Johannes_B `report`*. My bad

Comment: Your reference to page 14 doesn't look like your example. Do you mean page 15? I think you should add a picture to your question. Do you really use `report` or `scrreprt`?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I believe numbers of examples are at the top of example. However, I added a picture to question. I am using `report`, but maybe I messed up something in my question, as so far I was only basic LaTeX user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I tried some things and hope I got it right, but you will need to adjust it to your needs. It is basically a combination of the both examples you printed.

```
\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height .8ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\partname}{Chapter}

\titleclass{\part}{top} % make part like a chapter
\titleformat{\part}
[display]
{\centering\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
{\thickhrulefill\hspace{.3cm}\MakeUppercase{\partname} \thepart\hspace{.3cm}\thickhrulefill\\*\titlerule[1pt]}
{-10pt}
{\huge\MakeUppercase}
[{\titlerule[2pt]}]
%
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
%
```

Adjustments that are reasonable

- The thickness of the first rule, defined in the `\def` part. I tried without this but failed, and you can probaly make it adjustable, but I guess there is no need. I copied this from your [second example](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html), by the way.
- To get your wish with **Chapter** as part you will have to redefine `\partname`. I went for the simple method here, but be warned, in combination with babel this *might* be more complex. However, you probably know a (La)Tex help site which you can search for that.
- `{-10pt}` as part of the `\titelformat` command. It defines the distance between the thin rule and the text "A PART". However, probably due to the `\\*` this is required to be negative, I found no way around this, but neither did I find a problem.
- font sizes should be obvious, I tried to adjust to your example.

There are tons of stuff to change, but this is the basic construct.The result will be:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and all that detailed explanation! I'll implement it to my file and look how it's working.