# Having multiple plays with dramatist

Tags: dramatist

I am trying to use package `dramatist` inside documentclass `book`.

My understanding of the documentation tells me that:

- The `\act` is defined as a *chapter*.
- The `\scene` is defined as a *section*.

I would like to have:

- `play` as a *chapter*
- `act` as a *section*
- `scene` as a *subsection*
- and `\DramPer` as a *section* (this one is optionally required)

Is it possible to achieve this result? I mean, is it possible to have multiple plays in one book, and having table of contents with play/act/scene in it?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Would `play` perhaps be better as a `part`?

Comment: `part` may be acceptable, but `\part{My Play}` is printing "Part I \n My Play" on a single page. I would like to get "My Play" without the "Part I", and as a chapter title, not on its own page.

Comment: You can achieve that by adjusting the part format. There are many options how to do that. Have a look at some posts here on TeX.SX.

Comment: See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30432/15925