# \part page styling

Tags: parts

I'm trying to chage the style of \part to prevent a new part to take all a page and align it on right, like the attached picture

Can someone help me please ?

Thanks very much in advance !!

From
[image]
To
[image: Desired \part style]

Comment: Which document class are you using? Have a look at the column to the right, there is a similar question. Maybe it helps.

Comment: I'm currently using report class, I saw the question, I'm trying some things with the answser but it's far from what I would like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally made it with package titlesec and this post:[Styling the \part page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30432/styling-the-part-page?rq=1)

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleclass{\part}{top} % make part like a chapter
\titleformat{\part}
[display]
{\raggedleft\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{\vspace{3pt}\MakeUppercase{\partname} \thepart}
{0pt}
{\vspace{1pc}\huge\MakeUppercase}
%
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
%

\begin{document}

\part{Test part title}
\section{Test section azeazr}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Result]