# fancyhdr not showing up on all pages of appendix

Tags: tables, fancyhdr, appendix

I'm trying to get a fancyhdr onto all pages of my appendix. The header and footer don't continue to the end of the section. There are different sections of the appendix (Appendix A, Appendix B, C, ...).

In the MWE, the fancyhdr stop after page 5. A MWE with my preamble is below. Should compile with pdflatex (maybe lualatex).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[main=english,german]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\makeatletter                           %% Define a HUGE font size
\newcommand\HUGE{\@setfontsize\Huge{35}{35}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\newcommand{\sbx}[2][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleclass{\part}{top}                 % formatting part pages (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431868/part-page-styling?rq=1)
\titleformat{\part}
[display]
{\thispagestyle{empty}\raggedleft\fontfamily{LinuxBiolinumT-OsF}\selectfont\HUGE\bfseries}
{\vspace{9cm}\MakeUppercase{\partname} \thepart}
{0pt}
{\vspace{10.5cm}\titlerule[.7pt]\vspace{.5cm}\Huge}

\titleclass{\chapter}{top}              % formatting chapter pages (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431868/part-page-styling?rq=1)
\titleformat{\chapter}
[display]
{\raggedleft\fontfamily{LinuxBiolinumT-OsF}\selectfont\HUGE\bfseries}
%{\vspace{-2cm}{}}
{\vspace{1cm}{\chaptername} \thechapter}
{0pt}
{\vspace{1pc}\Huge}
%
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{1.8cm}{1cm}
%


\usepackage{afterpage}                                  % command for blank pages
\newcommand\blankpage{
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage
}

\usepackage{emptypage}              % additional package for blank pages

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
        Number of points, Values
        10, 100
        20, 400
        30, 1200
        40, 2345
    \end{filecontents*}
    

    \renewcommand\chaptername{Appendix}     % change "chapter" header to "appendix
    
    \newpage
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \part*{Appendix}    
    \clearpage
    \begin{appendices}
        \newpage
        \renewcommand\thefigure{A.\arabic{figure}} 
        \renewcommand\thetable{A.\arabic{table}} 
        \setcounter{table}{0}
        \setcounter{figure}{0}
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        \fancyhead{}
        \fancyhead[LE, RO]{\textbf{Appendix A}}
        \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
        \chapter*{Appendix A: My title} \label{app:A}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{A: My title}
        
        \section*{My section 1}
        \lipsum[1]
        \subsection*{My subsection 1}
        \lipsum[2-4]
        \section*{My section 2}
        \begin{table*}[!htbp]
            \centering
            \caption{My table}
            \begin{footnotesize}
                \pgfplotstabletypeset[
                assign column name/.style={/pgfplots/table/column name={\textbf{#1}}},
                col sep=comma,
                column type=,
                begin table={\begin{tabularx}{.95\linewidth}{X c }},
                    end table={\end{tabularx}},
                string type,
                columns/0/.style={string type,column name={}},
                columns/1/.style={string type,column name={}},
                every head row/.style={
                    before row={\toprule\addlinespace},
                    after row=\bottomrule\addlinespace},
                every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
                ]{data.csv} 
            \end{footnotesize}
            \label{table}
        \end{table*}
        \subsection*{My subsection 1}
        \lipsum[2-4]
        \begin{table*}[!htbp]
            \centering
            \caption{My table}
            \begin{footnotesize}
                \pgfplotstabletypeset[
                assign column name/.style={/pgfplots/table/column name={\textbf{#1}}},
                col sep=comma,
                column type=,
                begin table={\begin{tabularx}{.95\linewidth}{X c }},
                    end table={\end{tabularx}},
                string type,
                columns/0/.style={string type,column name={}},
                columns/1/.style={string type,column name={}},
                every head row/.style={
                    before row={\toprule\addlinespace},
                    after row=\bottomrule\addlinespace},
                every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
                ]{data.csv} 
            \end{footnotesize}
            \label{table}
        \end{table*}
        \begin{table*}[!htbp]
            \centering
            \caption{My table}
            \begin{footnotesize}
                \pgfplotstabletypeset[
                assign column name/.style={/pgfplots/table/column name={\textbf{#1}}},
                col sep=comma,
                column type=,
                begin table={\begin{tabularx}{.95\linewidth}{X c }},
                    end table={\end{tabularx}},
                string type,
                columns/0/.style={string type,column name={}},
                columns/1/.style={string type,column name={}},
                every head row/.style={
                    before row={\toprule\addlinespace},
                    after row=\bottomrule\addlinespace},
                every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
                ]{data.csv} 
            \end{footnotesize}
            \label{table}
        \end{table*}
        \begin{table*}[!htbp]
            \centering
            \caption{My table}
            \begin{footnotesize}
                \pgfplotstabletypeset[
                assign column name/.style={/pgfplots/table/column name={\textbf{#1}}},
                col sep=comma,
                column type=,
                begin table={\begin{tabularx}{.95\linewidth}{X c }},
                    end table={\end{tabularx}},
                string type,
                columns/0/.style={string type,column name={}},
                columns/1/.style={string type,column name={}},
                every head row/.style={
                    before row={\toprule\addlinespace},
                    after row=\bottomrule\addlinespace},
                every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
                ]{data.csv} 
            \end{footnotesize}
            \label{table}
        \end{table*}
        \begin{table*}[!htbp]
            \centering
            \caption{My table}
            \begin{footnotesize}
                \pgfplotstabletypeset[
                assign column name/.style={/pgfplots/table/column name={\textbf{#1}}},
                col sep=comma,
                column type=,
                begin table={\begin{tabularx}{.95\linewidth}{X c }},
                    end table={\end{tabularx}},
                string type,
                columns/0/.style={string type,column name={}},
                columns/1/.style={string type,column name={}},
                every head row/.style={
                    before row={\toprule\addlinespace},
                    after row=\bottomrule\addlinespace},
                every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
                ]{data.csv} 
            \end{footnotesize}
            \label{table}
        \end{table*}
        \begin{table*}[!htbp]
            \centering
            \caption{My table}
            \begin{footnotesize}
                \pgfplotstabletypeset[
                assign column name/.style={/pgfplots/table/column name={\textbf{#1}}},
                col sep=comma,
                column type=,
                begin table={\begin{tabularx}{.95\linewidth}{X c }},
                    end table={\end{tabularx}},
                string type,
                columns/0/.style={string type,column name={}},
                columns/1/.style={string type,column name={}},
                every head row/.style={
                    before row={\toprule\addlinespace},
                    after row=\bottomrule\addlinespace},
                every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
                ]{data.csv} 
            \end{footnotesize}
            \label{table}
        \end{table*}
    \end{appendices}
    
    \afterpage{\blankpage}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please reduce your [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that it only includes the necessary parts. Your code is way to long and does not even compile for me.

Comment: @marv: I edited the code to make it shorter. Does it compile now?

Comment: yes, the old code only compiled with pdflatex, not with lualatex. The new one compiles with both. But you should add the `\documentclass` back

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed. Any clever solutions? :)

Comment: You should't hardcode the Appendix A in the header. LaTeX provides mechanism for that, such as `\leftmark`. However, this does not work with the starred commands such as `\chapter*`. Why are you not using the normal sectioning commands?

Comment: I figured it out. Moving the lines from `\pagestye{fancy}` up to `\fancyfoot` before `\begin{appendices` fixes your problem.

Comment: I need all of that after `\begin{appendices}` because I have different appendices (Appendix A, B, C, D, E), and that code changes the header for each appendix "chapter"...I'm getting the feeling that I should be doing this differently, but I don't know how.

Comment: So I moved `\pagestye{fancy}` before `\begin{appendices}`, and now there's a header on the remaining pages, but it's the wrong one (it's from the "References" section above (not in the MWE)).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132952/discussion-between-marv-and-sp1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your `\pagestyle` definitions inside the `appendices` environment is that these definitions are local to the environment. When the environment finishes the definition that was active outside the environment is restored. In  your case that is `\pagestyle{empty}`.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Put the definition before the `appendices` environment. As you noted this only will work if you have a definition that works for multiple appendices. This can be done if you use `\leftmark` instead of the appendix title in `\fancyhead`.
2. Add a `\clearpage` before `\end{appendices}`. This causes all pages to be generated with the proper headers, before the header definitions are reset. Adding a `\clearpage` is a good idea anyhow, because it flushes all pending figures and tables in the appendices section.

And after the `\clearpage, you can just use` \blankpage`. No need for` \afterpage`.

By the way, I don't think you really use the functionality of the `appendices` environment, so you could probably get rid of it.

To have complete control of your headers and table of contents for the appendices, you can use `\chapter*` as you have noted, but then you have to add `\markboth` yourself for the headers. Also you have to increment the chapter (=appendix) number yourself. The best way is to define a macro that does the work.

So here is the solution:

```
\newcommand{\Achapter}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{chapter}
  \chapter*{\appendixname\ \thechapter: #1}
  \markboth{\appendixname\ \thechapter}{}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\thechapter: #1}
}
. . .
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        \setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
        \fancyhead{}
        \fancyhead[LE, RO]{\textbf{\leftmark}}
        \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
        % \chapter*{Appendix A: My title} \label{app:A}
        % \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{A: My title}
        \Achapter{My Title}
. . .
        \clearpage
    \end{appendices}
    \blankpage
```